# A correct way for the integer wrap around?

Tags: c++, operators, bitwise-operators

What would be a relatively better / more correct way to ensure that the integer value always gets a wrap around **from 0 to max 8** in a for loop? (*I'm using 32 iterations just as and example here*) I have found three options (A, B, and C)

Example:

```
int x = 0;
const int max = 8; // EDIT: Always in the power of two.

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    // EDIT: "x++;" usage was incorrect here.
    x = i;

//  x = x % max;  // A
//  x &= max - 1; // B
//  x &= ~max;    // C (EDIT: Incorrect, dont use...)

    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:** Performance is critical, need the fastest solution.
I saw the use of "**x &= ~max**" in some third party performance critical code. Looks like they do a wrap around using this trick. Is it valid or faster then other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: `x %= max` is probably the most understandable.

Comment: How do you know it's performance critical? Did you measure it? Intuition is as reliable as a coin flip for guessing what code is critical and what code isn't.

Comment: The code "x &= ~max" was used in one of production ready real-time code, so I'm just assuming there was a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `int` the bit mask (`x &= (max-1);`) and modulo (`x %= max;`) solutions produce different assembly because it they produce different results for negative values. While the module solution may be easier to read, it might run slower than the module solution. Usually you would use `x %= max;` as that expresses exactly what you want to do, but if performance is critical the bit mask solution is worth considering.

Note that for `unsigned int` gcc compiles both solutions to use a single `and` instruction.

Godbolt : https://godbolt.org/z/WAckr7

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question. Do you have any ideas on the "x &= ~max" method?

Comment: I've tested this method and it worked with no problem. I will probably need to look more into it...

Comment: @Gediminas It works provided the value never reaches 16. It just makes sure the 4th bit is always 0.

Comment: you were right.I've made a mistake by using "x++;" in my test code... That made my value wrap around from 0-7 with "~max", so I was confused...

Answer (score 2):

Both B and C are valid in this particular case, but only work when `max` is exactly a power of two.  If it is not, `%=` will be as fast as anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If [0,8) are valid and max is guaranteed to be the power of 2, `x &= (max-1)` works and is faster than the first. Can't say about C.